# Column Major Order

Tags: data-structures, arrays, c

I have a doubt understanding How a 3-Dimensional array is stored in column Major Order. An array in Row Major order is stored like **[plane][row][column]** So, for finding address of any element we cross planes first, rows next and then some elements in that column.

But How is a 3-Dimensional array stored in Column Major Order?

It's better if understood from a problem.

> A is an array $[2.....6,3.....8,4.......10]$ of elements. The starting
>   location is $500$. The location of an element $A(5,5,5)$ using column
>   major order is __________.

Comment: I do not understand your shifted array notation and it looks like school excersise (I might be wrong, should that be the case I am sorry for that), so it would be bad to give the answer, but I can check it if you describe what it is about and confirm your calculation if you need that. $A[0][0][0]$ has index $500$?

Comment: Above array notation means array  as $A[5][6][7]$, but array indices start from $2,3$ and $4$ respectively. Btw no one gives homework like this in india.

Answer (score 1):

In the Row-major order the elements of rows are continous, so you have already described the Column-major order.

X-major order means that n-dimensional array when stored in the memory is flat for easy, sequential access if the X entries.

To find address of any element of the Column-major order: the first is plane, than row and *the last is column*.